In vsCode, staging *blocks* (using the built-in Source Control) changes the whole file EOL
I would expect it to keep the original EOL.
In VScode settings, EOL is set to auto.
Staging whole file keeps the original EOL either by source control built-in extension or git command from git bash.
Unstaging file doesn't change the EOL back.
I have the latest visual code version 1.95.3
